# How do I debug a process in XCode?

Tags: xcode, debugging

Here's my situation.  I have an app installed on my system.  It's running.  I also have the source for this app and I've built it in XCode and had it generate dSYM files.  I attached to the process in XCode.  I've been trying to set breakpoints of the form "-[ClassName methodName]" (without the quotes) however none of my breakpoints are getting hit.  Do I have to somehow point XCode to my symbol file or something?

Answer (score 0):

I have never debugged using that method, but there is a much easier way. You can simply click on the line number of a code-bearing line and a blue arrow (a breakpoint) will appear there. When the application reaches one of these lines with a breakpoint, execution will pause an allow you to step through the code one line at a time.